# Need help centering my Isotope container

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a group of thumbnails that I want to center as the columns drop off, is there an easy way to do that.

Here is the example
http://turnpost.turnpostinteractive.com/all-work/

Here is the jquery

```
function initIsotope() {
    // Init Portfolio masonry
    var $container = $('.portfolio-container');
    $container.isotope({
        resizable: false,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 291,
            gutterWidth: 10
        }
    });

    $(".filter-portfolio li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.filters').find('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');


        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
            filter: selector,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 291,
                gutterWidth: 10
            }
        }, function() {
            // Refresh waypoints
            $.waypoints('refresh');
        });

        return false;
    });

  $('.noclick').off('click');

    // Init Portfolio masonry
    $('.entries-container').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.blog-entry'
    });
}

function reLayoutIsotope() {
    $('.isotope').isotope( 'reLayout' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the css? Do they have exact widths or percentages?
If you have a conatiner around them, you can absolute position is. Then, give the container a width(any will do.) Position the container negative half of the width. Then give it a margin-left of 50%; Example below.

Html

```
<div class="container">
    ...stuff
</div>
```

Css

```
.container {position:absolute; left:-300px; width:600px; margin-left:50%;}
```

That will move the container 50% from the left side of page. It will then move it back to the left by half the width of the container. Positioning the middle of the element with the middle of the page.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dead center in the screen use some css like this:

```
.portfolio-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px; /* change this to how large you want it to be width-wise */
}
```